# Обрезка картинки в upload media wordpress

Tags: wordpress, crop

Изначально, при загрузке в админ-панели wordpress какой-либо картинки - она загружается, а затем создается несколько её дубликатов разных размеров. Вопрос мой вот в чём, могу ли я вмешаться в момент загрузки картинки, задать свои custom размеры картинок, что я желаю получить и не создавать стандартные wordpress`овские [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [add_image_size()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_image_size), [remove_image_size()](https://wp-kama.com/function/remove_image_size)

Answer (score 0):

> и не создавать стандартные wordpress`овские

Чтобы не создавать "стандартные wordpress`овские" **миниатюры** достаточно выставить нули в настройках медиа.

Однако:

1. темы и плагины всё равно будут создвать свои миниатюры.
2. Удалять ни ВП-шые ни другие миниатюры не стоит - они примеряются для разных условий вывода.